# SSL stapling and variable SSL certificates in NGINX

Tags: nginx, ssl, ocsp

I have several domains, all of which are served by the same NGINX instance. I am trying to setup a generic server configuration for HTTPS, such that every domain uses its own certificate and has SSL stapling enabled. These settings as defined in `default.conf` are as follows:

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256;

    ssl_stapling        on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    ssl_trusted_certificate /ssl/chain.pem;

    ssl_certificate     /ssl/$ssl_server_name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/$ssl_server_name/privkey.pem;
}
```

Every domain has a server block assigned to it in separate configuration files, inheriting the SSL settings as defined above. For example, `example.conf` would say:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        return 200 "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. With this configuration, running `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -status` results in a message saying `OCSP response: no response sent`.

Interestingly, when I change the configuration to not use `$ssl_server_name` but one of the domain names (lets say `example.com`, see snippet below), I *do* receive a proper OCSP response for that specific domain. As expected, this fails for the other domains since the wrong certificate is provided.

```
server {
    ...
    ssl_certificate     /ssl/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ...
}
```

This is no solution to me of course, because it still requires me to specify each certificate per domain.

## Questions

1. Is it possible to combine the usage of `$ssl_server_name` and SSL stapling and if so, how?
2. Is the behaviour of NGINX as I have described it expected/documented?
3. Are there any issues with the configuration presented here that might cause trouble?

Comment: What version of OpenSSL? Below 1.1.1, `openssl s_client` does not send SNI by default; you must specify e.g. `-servername example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of `ssl_stapling on` being silently disregarded when *using variables in the file name* is tracked as [defect #1813](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1813).

The only documentation that even suggests that this is a special case is [in the documentation of the `ssl_certificate` directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) (emphasis mine):

> Since version 1.15.9, variables can be used in the file name when
> using OpenSSL 1.0.2 or higher:
>
> ```
> ssl_certificate     $ssl_server_name.crt;
> ssl_certificate_key $ssl_server_name.key;
> ```
>
> Note that using variables implies that **a certificate will be loaded
> for each SSL handshake**, and this may have a negative impact on
> performance.

There currently appear to be no plans to complete the "variables in ssl_* directives" implementation in this and related regards.

If you have no way of speeding this up by paying someone to do so, you might be interested in also watching progress on [enhancement #813](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/812) - a mechanism able to fetch and store OCSP responses before they already would have been needed likely solves *most* of your problem as well. Assuming that solutions comes in the form of a dynamic certificate cache, that could then be initialized by simply sending a request to all known domains to have them loaded.

---

Until then, just have your nginx configuration be statically listing all the domains *and* the repeated mentions of them in filenames.. use configuration management software (such as Ansible) to ease the job of generating updates and issuing reloads.

In any case, do define a static, separate `default_server` block for those poor non-SNI clients. Nginx has a few surprising interactions between per-server configuration and the treatment of clients that do not say which one they meant to talk to.

Comment: Great explanation, exactly what I was looking for. It's unfortunate that NGINX does not support a more dynamic way of configuring webservers, but it's good that I now know for sure. I will look into software that can help me with this as you've suggested. Thank you!